# Grails export plugin customization

Tags: grails

The [Grails export plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export) can be used to export domain objects but what if I want to export domain objects *AND* some other information before and/or after my domain object list into a text file according to some specified xsd schema? Is it better to modify this plugin and tailor it to those needs or is there a better more flexible solution?

Comment: Without seeing an example of what you are trying to do it's hard to advise you much more than saying: You can build list of maps of your data, pulling some of it from one source, and others from your domain classes, then use the plugin to export the data in your list of maps which has both.

Comment: @Joshua Moore Ok thanks that sounds like an interesting approach. This was actually a question about something I haven't gotten to doing yet but it was worrying me in the back of my head. Therefore I can't provide details as I haven't delved into it and thought of them. Perhaps I'll refresh the topic if I feel the need to revisit.